# Angular controller references instances exists after ngDestroy

Tags: javascript, angular

Please have a look on following StackBlitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-yyspeh). Please open Dev tools and have a look on console output while switching back and forth between login & home links. Each toggle will add instance of `HomeViewComponent` to out development array.

### Small code tour for those, who don't like to go through it on their own:

App component code handles routing of app. There are singe router outlet that will load one of two views. Enabling view A forces view B to be pushed via `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook. There are no pending subscriptions in any of components, no child references, no implicit or explicit references to components, no nothing. In other words, after `ngOnDestory`, component can be safely discarded.

It turns out, that old component references are not discarded anyhow, remains stuck by Angular.

Same behavior would be achieved if:

- References would be stored inside some service array
- No reference would be stores, but memory footprint would be browsed in dev Tools

### The question is:

- Why angular seems not to care about old components, that shall be
  scrapped?
- How this can be explicitly requested by app developer?

### Disclaimer

This topic was already discussed on Angular bug tracking github forum. The dev team claims were clear: this will not happen when in production mode. If you examine `main.ts` file, you might see, this behavior still occurs. Beside this, we got real-life examples of production apps that accumulates dead components over time.

I'm adding `JavaScript` tag, because this might be related in some V8/any other JS engine implementation.

This issue and example was generously provided by [JoshThunar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7463775/joshthunar), many thanks for support.